# Overwriting files on local disk from github (using Laravel framework)

Tags: php, git, laravel, github, laravel-5

I'm trying do to the following:

1) Create a new laravel project using:

```
sudo composer create-project laravel/laravel /var/www/html/laravel5`
```

2) Overwrite only the different files from github. I want to keep the following files and folders unchanged:

- `.env`
- `.env.example`
- `.gitattributes`
- `.gitignore`
- `vendor/`

Clone from github is not working because the folder is not empty.

The only workaround that I found is:

1. create a new project
2. copy the files and folders that I want to another folder
3. clone the project from github
4. copy the files back to the folder

I'm using Xubuntu, Laravel 5.0 and Github.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by 'overwrite only the different files from github'? Which git repo are you cloning from?

Comment: My repository. I want to keep the files created with 'laravel new' command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this via an all-git method rather than copy/paste from another directory. (I'm not sure why your workaround is a bad solution, though.)

The basic plan is:

1. Create a repository.
2. Checkout some bogus branch that you won't keep around.
3. Add the directories you want to keep to the index and commit them.
4. Force a checkout to the branch you want. It probably will need forcing because of the other things you *didn't* just commit.
5. Apply the patch of the recently created commit to your working directory.

And in commands:

```
cd /path/to/repo
git init
git branch temp-branch
git add .env && git add .env.example && git add .gitattributes && git add .gitignore && git add vendor/
git commit -m "Sustain Local Changes"
git remote add origin https://github.com/owner/repo
git fetch
git checkout -f master # Should detect origin/master. If it doesn't, just set a branch up manually. Replace master if that's not the branch you want.
git merge --no-commit --no-ff temp-branch
```

Personally, I find this a lot more ugly than your workaround.

Comment: I realized you might have a conflict on the merge. If so, just use one of the -X commands. Probably `theirs`.